Why we can't use stride and dilation rate at the same time in causal convolution?
I would like to understand why we can't use a stride different from 1 and a dilation rate different from 1 at the same time.
The following code will raise an error:
c1 = Conv1D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, strides=2, padding='causal',dilation_rate=2, activation='relu')(input_layer)

I want to use them at the same time, but i can't. (I'm using Tensorflow & Keras)

Hi @Yidiiiir , You are trying to use both strides and dilation, there are some Mismatch with Causal Padding
Thus, causal padding intends to keep the output size same as of the input size so that only the past values contribute to the current output. If the strides are more than 1, the output length is smaller thus breaking causal padding’s objectives.
